# Calling member function with reference to pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, accessor

I have a class `CaloReader` that creates a pointer `_calo` to an object called `Calorimeter` containing a grid of cells with an ID number. This pointer is then used to set an ID number to each cell. Futhermore, I have a accessor `const Calorimeter& calo()` that returns a reference of this pointer. Now, I want to create a function `dumpReadoutMap()` that prints out all ID numbers of all cells. The function is called from my main file as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CaloCell.hh"
#include "CaloGrid.hh"
#include "Point.hh"
#include "Calorimeter.hh"
#include "CaloReader.hh"

int main(){

    CaloReader r("calo.dat");
    r.calo().dumpReadoutMap();

}
```

The problem with my code is that the complirer gives the following error:

```
error: ‘const class Calorimeter’ has no member named ‘dumpReadoutMap’
 r.calo().dumpReadoutMap();
```

The only relevant file for this question is the below as the other ones are correct and cannot be changed.

```
#ifndef CALOREADER_HH
#define CALOREADER_HH

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Calorimeter.hh"

#include "CaloReaderException.hh"
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

class CaloReader {

public:

    CaloReader(const char* file): _file(file) {

        Calorimeter* _calo = 0;
        ifstream _file(file);

        std::string word;
        _file >> word;

        _file >> word; //Reads in next word.
        if(word=="SIZE") {
            int size_x;
            int size_y;
            _file >> size_x;
            _file >> size_y;

            _calo = new Calorimeter(size_x,size_y);

        }
        _file >> word;

        while(word=="POSITION") {
            int readoutID;
            int ix;
            int iy;
            _file >> readoutID >> ix >> iy;
            //std::cout << word << " " << readoutID << " " << ix << " " << iy << std::endl;
            _calo->grid().cell(ix,iy)->setID(readoutID);

            _file >> word;
        }
    }

    ~CaloReader() {}

    const Calorimeter& calo() const {
        return *_calo;
    }

    void dumpReadoutMap(std::ostream& os = std::cout) {


        for(int x =0; x<size_x; x++) {
            for(int y=0; y<size_y; y++) {
                os << std::setw(6) << grid().cell(x,y)->getID();
            }
            os << std::endl;
        }
    }


private:

    Calorimeter* _calo;
    std::ifstream _file;
    std::string word;

};
#endif
```

Comment: Is the `Calorimeter` class supposed to have a `dumpReadoutMap` member? Or is it only a member of the `CaloReader` class? It might be easier to understand why you get the errors if you think of your expression like `(r.calo()).dumpReadoutMap()`. I.e. `dumpReadoutMap` is called on what `r.calo()` ***returns***.

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: The latter one.

Comment: What's the purpose of calling `_calo->grid().cell(5,5);`? [line 56]

Comment: It was a test for me to see where the program breaks down but forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

`dumpReadoutMap` is a method in `CaloReader` class. So it must be called from a `CaloReader` object. You should use:

```
CaloReader r("calo.dat");
r.dumpReadoutMap();
```

Comment: Doing this gives a segmentation fault when trying to access one of the cells.

Comment: @RobSchneider: that means that you have stepped to next problem :-). More seriously, now it compiles, a debugger could help to control the values in `dumpReadoutMap` . But shouldn't it be **`_calo->`** `grid().cell(x,y)->getID();`?

Comment: But is the segmentation fault not due to the fact that the function does not have access to the `grid()` , therefore it tries to access something non-existing?

Answer (score 0):

Since calo() returns a const reference, you can't call a non-const member function with it.  It's disappointing the error message doesn't explain clearly what the error is.

Comment: Removing the `const` part still gives the same error.

Comment: Here is some code based on what's in the question that compiles.  The full intent of the coder is not clear to me, so it may not be helpful.  https://godbolt.org/g/Bzimb3